# How do I specify a directory for properties files in a jar manifest classpath?

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I'd like to put all of the .properties files that my executable jar requires in a sub-directory off of the directory from which I will run the jar file. Currently, my MANIFEST.MF looks something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_26
Main-Class: MyMainClass
Class-Path: . conf lib/dependency1.jar
```

If I keep my .properties files in the same directory as the jar file, everything works fine. If I move them to the `conf` sub-directory, they are not found. I've also tried specifying the paths to the .properties files directly, such as `conf/log4j.properties`.

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

**Update:** Here's an example of code in my executable jar that fails:

```
InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myproperties.properties");
```

When `myproperties.properties` is in the `conf` sub-directory, this statement returns a null InputStream. When `log4j.properties` is in the `conf` sub-directory, it outputs its warning message about not finding its configuration:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (MyMainClass).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Comment: Who's loading the properties files? The executabele JAR? Or the `dependency1.jar`? And how exactly?

Comment: Updated the question with more details about the failures.

Comment: Do you really need to have them in a different run location or is this more about organizing them in a different source folder in your development hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, this is about location at runtime. It's more of a want than a need, though ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(String configFilename)`

This can be used to specify where your log file is located.

There is an example of that here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html